# Storybook extend component interface for story controls only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have a modal that I animate in and out using framer-motion that looks something like this.

```
<AnimatePresence>
    { isOpen && <Modal /> }
</AnimatePresence>
```

As you can see the modal does not accept an isOpen prop and instead is shown in the DOM based on the parent state. In `storybook` I am trying to add this `isOpen` boolean in the storybook actions but I am running into Typescript errors extending the StoryObj type

```
const meta = {
    component: Modal,
    argTypes: {
        // Modal Arg Types here
    }
    args: {
        isOpen: {
            description: 'Toggle the modal open and closed',
            control: 'boolean',
            table: {
                category: 'Behaviour',
                defaultValue: { summary: false },
            },
    },
    parameters: {
        layout: 'centered',
        controls: {
            expanded: true,
        },
    },
} satisfies Meta<typeof Modal & { isOpen: boolean }>

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Modal & { isOpen: boolean }>

export const Modal: Story = {
    render: (args: any) => {
        const [{ isOpen }] = useArgs()

        return <Modal {...args} />
    },
}
```

The error I am getting is referencing the fact that `isOpen` is not a type that exists on `modal` when storybook is getting the inferred component type.

I am trying to extend the story interface in order to have `isOpen` in my controls but when I try to extend `type Story = StoryObj<typeof Modal>` I keep getting this typescript error

```
Type '{ isOpen: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Props>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'isOpen' does not exist in type 'Partial<Props>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Storybook has an example in its docs of [fully custom args](https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.5/essentials/controls#fully-custom-args), as shown here:

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

import { Page } from './Page';

type PagePropsAndCustomArgs = React.ComponentProps<typeof Page> & { footer?: string };

const meta: Meta<PagePropsAndCustomArgs> = {
  component: Page,
  render: ({ footer, ...args }) => (
    <Page {...args}>
      <footer>{footer}</footer>
    </Page>
  ),
};
export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<PagePropsAndCustomArgs>;

export const CustomFooter: Story = {
  args: {
    footer: 'Built with Storybook',
  },
};
```

So your example would be something like...

```
type StoryArgs = React.ComponentProps<typeof Modal> & { isOpen?: boolean }

const meta: Meta<StoryArgs> = {
    component: Modal,
    argTypes: {
        // Modal Arg Types here
    }
    args: {
        isOpen: {
            description: 'Toggle the modal open and closed',
            control: 'boolean',
            table: {
                category: 'Behaviour',
                defaultValue: { summary: false },
            },
    },
    parameters: {
        layout: 'centered',
        controls: {
            expanded: true,
        },
    },
}

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<StoryArgs>

export const Modal: Story = {
    render: (args) => {
        const [{ isOpen }] = useArgs()

        return <Modal {...args} />
    },
}
```

This should cover both the `args` *and* the `argTypes`, and also when you pass `args` to the `render` function too.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you for linking to the official Storybook docs too!

Answer (score 0):

Add args:

```
type Story = StoryObj<typeof Modal> & { args: { isOpen?: boolean } };
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @maxim-arnayt, @naszy
 This helps with `args`, doesn't solve for the `argsTypes`. Any tips on this?

Comment: `type Story = StoryObj<typeof Modal> & { argTypes: { isOpen?: InputType } }`